# Display datetime model property as Short date time string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm new with MVC2, and am having a formatting problem. I have a DateTime property in my Employee model that I would like displayed with the Short Date Time.

This however, does not appear to be the correct method.

```
1 <div class="editor-field">
2    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateRequested.ToShortDateString()) %>
3    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateRequested) %>
4 </div>
```

Line 2 throws this exception:

> Templates can be used only with field
>   access, property access,
>   single-dimension array index, or
>   single-parameter custom indexer
>   expressions.

What is the correct way to handle formatting in mvc?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try decorating your view model property with the [`[DisplayFormat]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime DateRequested { get; set; };
```

and in your view use the `Html.EditorFor` helper:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateRequested) %>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateRequested) %>
</div>
```

or if you insist on using textbox helper (don't know why would you but anyway here's how):

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.TextBox("DateRequested", Model.DateRequested.ToShortDateString()) %>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateRequested) %>
</div>
```

Comment: I wonder what is the difference between .EditorFor and .TextBox is. Either way this is exactly what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: @asawyer, the difference is that a TextBox helper **always** generates an `<input type="text" ...` whereas an EditorFor could be customized and could generate whatever you tell it to. For example on scalar properties such as string, int it would generate an `<input type="text" ...` but you have complete control over it on your view model. You could even have a completely personalized editor template where it would generate a jquery-ui date picker for a DateTime field on your view model. That's the power of editor templates.

Comment: Sounds like I need to break down and buy a book on the subject ><

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick with an html helper method, try this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxDateTime<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,
             Expression<Func<TModel, DateTime>> expression, int tabIndex = 1)
    {
        var meta = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
        var propertyName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);

        var input = new TagBuilder("input");
        input.MergeAttribute("id",
                             helper.AttributeEncode(helper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(propertyName)));
        input.MergeAttribute("name",
                             helper.AttributeEncode(
                                 helper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(propertyName)));
        input.MergeAttribute("value", ((DateTime)meta.Model).ToShortDateString());
        input.MergeAttribute("type", "text");
        input.MergeAttribute("class", "text cal");
        input.MergeAttribute("tabindex", tabIndex.ToString());
        input.MergeAttributes(helper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression), meta));
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(input.ToString());
    }
```